# Parallelize Pandas CSV Writing

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to write multiple CSVs out simultaneously? At the moment, I do a listdir() on an outputs directory, and iterate one-by-one through a list of files. I would ideally like to write them all at the same time.

Has anyone had any experience in this before?

Comment: Most likely the solution will be to roll your own multiprocessing logic, or to use dask. Check that out package first ;)

Comment: Do you have multiple HDDs (spindles)? Or do you have one or more SSDs?

Comment: @MaxU Only 1 HDD

Comment: @Ignacio I use Dask for my own personal stuff at home. Not at option at work unfortunately. I guess rolling my own multiprocessing logic in Python 2.7 is going to be the way forward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one HDD (not even an SSD drive), then the disk IO is your bottleneck and you'd better write to it sequentially instead of writing in parallel. The disk head needs to be positioned before writing, so trying to write in parallel will most probably be slower compared to one writer process. It would make sense if you would have multiple disks...